# Why is Eevee HDRI lighting much darker than Cycles?

Tags: 3d-view, eevee-render-engine, lighting, hdri

I'm noticing a drastic lighting difference in the viewport when using an HDRI image and switching from Eevee Render to Cycles Render. Screenshot examples attached. (1st is Cycles, 2nd is Eevee, 3rd is Eevee with increased background strength) Even when raising the background strength in Eevee, it produces a dull, washed out result.

I've heard Cycles renders light much more accurately, which I understand but comparing the lighting in a tutorial I'm following, my issue seems to be more drastic? Thoughts/Insight on what may be causing this?

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

[image]